# error while drawing several x-marks on a binary image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to draw several **x-marks** on a **binary image** to some co-ordinates.
My *output* should look like this

[image]

**To do this i have written some codes below**

```
clear all;

% Here four co-ordinates are provided as an example. In my main code the co-  ordinates will be hundred or thousands 
position{1}.x = 10;
position{1}.y = 10;
position{2}.x = 20;
position{2}.y = 20;
position{3}.x = 30;
position{3}.y = 30;
position{4}.x = 40;
position{4}.y = 40;

% Read image as binary
image = imread('test34.jpg');
figure('name','Main Image'),imshow(image);

gray_image=rgb2gray(image);
level = graythresh(gray_image);
binary_image = im2bw(image,level);

% Define color of the x-marker and initializing shapes which i want to draw
red = uint8([255 0 0]);
markerInserter = vision.MarkerInserter('Shape','X-mark','BorderColor','Custom','CustomBorderColor',red);

i = 1;
% The loop will continue to the number of co-ordinates which will never be predefined in my main code

while i<=numel(position) 
    % Converting binary to RGB for only once. 
    if i == 1
        rgb = repmat(binary_image, [1, 1, 3]);
    else

        rgb = repmat(binary_image, [1, 1, 1]);
    end       
    % Position where x-marks will be drawn

    Pts = int32([position{i}.x position{i}.y]);
    % Draw x-marks  
    binary_image = step(markerInserter, rgb, Pts);

    i = i+1;
end

figure('name','binary_image'),imshow(binary_image);
```

**But i am getting these errors**

> Error using images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData
>   (line 119)
>
> If input is logical (binary), it must be two-dimensional.
>
> Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 27)
>
> common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);
>
> Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
>
> common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);
>
> Error in imshow (line 227)
>
> [common_args,specific_args] = ...
>
> Error in test2 (line 39)
>
> figure('name','binary_image'),imshow(binary_image);

I have tried some examples but they are experimented on **RGB image** while **i need it on binary image** and that's where i am getting errors.

**Why i am getting these errors and what will be the solution?**

*Please provide explanation with proper code.*

Comment: So you wish to add red marks on a binary image? This will make a RGB image that's ok for you? Also you need to use `hold on` to avoid discarding the image when adding markers.

Comment: RGB will be fine. Actually it will be better if you follow my style of code. I have added comments to my code for better understanding @ Benoit_11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code seems a bit complicated (to me) for what it is intended. Here is a simple example demonstrating how to draw red crosses using `scatter` on a binary image. As you see, the image in itself is binary and the markers are in color, so the 'net' image is no longer binary... Also, there is no need to convert your RGB image to graylevels before applying `im2bw`.

And don't forget to use `hold on` to avoid discarding the image when adding the markers!

Here is the code with comments:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Read image
MyImage = imread('peppers.png');

%// Convert to binary. No need to use rgb2gray.
MyBWImage = im2bw(MyImage(:,:,2));

%// Define some x- and y positions for markers
xpositions = linspace(10,300,40);
ypositions = linspace(20,500,40);

imshow(MyBWImage)

%// IMPORTANT!!
hold on

%// Draw markers
scatter(xpositions.',ypositions.',80,'r','x')
```

With output:

[image]

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Why there are so many x-markers? In my main code, number of the co-ordinates of x-markers will be hundreds or thousands, Not fixed, That's why i have used while loop. If you have any other questions please feel free to ask @Benoit_11

Comment: I want to display my image at last, not first .@Benoit_11

Comment: It does not matter how many points you have, I drew many as an example. Moreover with `scatter` you need not worry about the number or whether you don't know it in advance, you can simply plot your whole x and y coordinates and Matlab takes care of the rest, as long as they contain the same number of elements. And the order in which you display the image does not make any difference in the end does it?

Comment: Sorry at first i didn't understand , now i understand. I have modified it a little bit for my work and it works. Thanks :)  @  Benoit_11